# Macro used in a .c file getting compiled without adding the header file in which it is defined

Tags: c, macros, header-files

I have a large project where some macro is defined as:

```
#define RECORD_COUNT 141 // in one file file1.h
```

Another file say file2.c is using this macro. But the file2.c is not including file1.h.

So is there a possibility that in on compiling the first file get pre-compiled is file1.h and the macro is added to the global scope. And this makes it possible to pre-compile the file2.c?

Comment: It might be getting included indirectly through other includes.

Comment: What do you mean by "another file say file2.c is using this macro?" What do you mean by "the macro is added to the global scope?" Macro expansion is done in a pre-processing stage -- there's no compilation, no scopes, no way that a file can say that another file is or isn't using a macro.

Comment: Wat i meant is like if a macro is defined in one file (file1), I believe the preprocessing and the compilation takes place in the order mentioned in the compilation list. So in this case where the macro is defined in one file and used in another even when the file is not included, is there a chance that the precompilation process replaces the macro in the 2nd file?????

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your macro definition are compiling before you are using it somewhere.

Just to check you can use `pragma message` to check if compiler touches that code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the header file directly to use it. There can be indirect includes as well.

For example,

Say file1.h has

```
#define RECORD_COUNT 141
```

file2.h has,

```
#include "file1.h"
...
...
```

If file2.c has `#include "file2.h"` then, you can use any macros or definition that are in 'file1.h' inside file2.c after that include statement.

Comment: No there is no hierarchical inclusion happened in this case.